# XAMPP on Linux

Tags: apache

Всем привет, установил XAMPP добавил 1 новый  Виртуальный хост, он добавился, но теперь при переходе на localhost и на мой новый домен, открывается один и тот-же сайт(который я залил), а как сделать так чтобы по localhost отображалась страничка XAMPP, а по моему домену test1.ru отображался мой сайт? Какие файлы нужно редактировать, и чт нужно редактировать? Я просто на Linux только 2-й день, а работать нужно.

**ФАЙЛ httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    DocumentRoot /www/yii.com/    ServerName yii.com    ServerAlias www.yii.com</VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>    DocumentRoot /www/lite-bux2.ru/    ServerName lite-bux2.ru    ServerAlias www.lite-bux2.ru</VirtualHost>
```

**ФАЙЛ /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost127.0.1.1   Android127.0.0.1   yii.com127.0.0.1   lite-bux2.ru# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopbackfe00::0 ip6-localnetff00::0 ip6-mcastprefixff02::1 ip6-allnodesff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Добавил ещё один домен, толку 0 всё равно отображается 1 сайт...

Comment: ну зачем зачем вам в линуксе XAMPP ?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию используется первый VirtualHost, попробуйте добавить перед первой секцией ещё одну:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      ServerName default      DocumentRoot <путь к странице XAMPP>  </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

В /etc/apache2/ports.conf, или где он у вас лежит.

Answer (score 0):

[Почитайте тут...](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/4081/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-apache2) Обсуждались уже виртуальные хосты...

UP

Если мне не изменяет память, то на ксамп попадете по

```
http://localhost/xampp/index.php
```